# Sorting Connected Edges in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, nodes, graph-theory

I have a list of edges stored in a random way and I am currently trying to rearrange them in a way they are all connected. I would like to know if is there anything already implemented in matlab for doing so or any algorithm I can look for to solve this.
Let me be a bit more specific

```
1  2
3  4
2  5
5  3
```

Must become

```
1   2
2   5
5   3
3   4
```

where the first number in each row is the second in the previous row.

I thank you guys in advance for your help.

Comment: Does every number appear exactly once in each column?

Comment: Yes, they do.  They have to. These are single and unique edges.

Comment: What version of MATLAB do you have? Do you have the Bioinformatics Toolbox? Ideally you would use a topological sort. If your graph is guaranteed to be well-behaved, then finding the start node and using DFS would be second best.

Comment: Matlab 2014, Ideally I would not need to use any toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `ismember` and `sort`:

```
E = [ ...
     1 2;
     3 4;
     2 5;
     5 3];

[~,M_IDX] = ismember(E(:,1),E(:,2));
[~,S_IDX] = sort(M_IDX);
G = E(S_IDX,:)

G =

   1   2
   2   5
   5   3
   3   4
```

Note this assumes that the graph is *very* well behaved, i.e. there is exactly *one* path from the start node to the end node, and that path traverses all of the edges.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can find easily where the start and end points.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly better ways to do this but you can do it with a for loop.

```
x=[1  2; 3  4; 2  5; 5  3]; % Your array
orderX=zeros([size(x,1),1);

orderX(1)=1;
for ii=2:size(x,1)
      orderX(ii)=find(x(orderX(ii-1),2)==x(:,1));
end
x=x(orderX,:);
```

This will only work if there are no repeated numbers and exactly one in each column. I'd recommend wrapping it in a function which inputs and outputs x.

You can easily extend this to work with more than one loop and more complex problems like that.